# How we can use secure vault in wso2esb

Tags: security, wso2, wso2-esb

I am using wso2esb4.8.0
how would i approach password hiding with secure vault option.
I am unable to find a proper docs.What is the connection between wso2carbon server and wso2esb.
If i wish to use secure vault in wso2esb i need to install wso2carbon server also or we have directly use that
i did the below changes in

```
/repository/conf/security/secret-config.properties
```

i have made below changes in this file but no use

```
#
#keystore.identity.location=/home/youtility2/Desktop/ESB/wso2/wso2esb-4.8.0/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks 
#keystore.identity.type=JKS
#keystore.identity.alias=wso2carbon
#keystore.identity.store.password=identity.store.password
#keystore.identity.store.secretProvider=com.sample.password.callback.handler.HardCodedSecretCallbackHandler
#secretRepositories.file.provider=org.wso2.securevault.secret.repository.FileBaseSecretRepositoryProvider

#secretRepositories.file.location=repository/conf/security/cipher-text.properties

#secretRepositories=file

#keystore.identity.key.password=identity.key.password

#carbon.secretProvider=org.wso2.securevault.secret.handler.SecretManagerSecretCallbackHandler

#keystore.identity.key.secretProvider=com.sample.password.callback.handler.HardCodedSecretCallbackHandler

#keystore.identity.alias=wso2carbon

#keystore.identity.key.password=wso2carbon
##keystore.identity.key.secretProvider=<any implementation of org.apache.synapse.commons.security.secret.SecretCallbackHandler>
##keystore.identity.parameters=enableHostnameVerifier=false;keyStoreCertificateFilePath=/home/esb.cer
#
#keystore.trust.location=repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks
#keystore.trust.type=JKS
#keystore.trust.alias=wso2carbon
#keystore.trust.store.password=wso2carbon
##keystore.trust.store.secretProvider=<any implementation of org.apache.synapse.commons.security.secret.SecretCallbackHandler>
#
```

and restarted the esb but i am unable to use secure vault

```
vault key="my.pwd.login"
pwd="****"
repeat="****"
```

getting errors from console like this

```
ERROR - CipherInitializer No secret repositories have been configured
[2014-02-05 14:50:50,547] ERROR - CipherInitializer Either Configuration properties can not be loaded or No secret repositories have been configured please check PRODUCT_HOME/repository/conf/security  refer links related to configure WSO2 Secure vault
[2014-02-05 14:50:50,547] ERROR - MediationSecurityAdminService Either Configuration properties can not be loaded or No secret repositories have been configured please check PRODUCT_HOME/repository/conf/security  refer links related to configure WSO2 Secure vault
[2014-02-05 14:50:50,548] ERROR - MediationSecurityAdminService Failed to load security key store information ,Configure secret-conf.properties properly by referring to http://docs.wso2.org/display/Carbon402/WSO2+Carbon+Secure+Vault
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Failed to load security key store information ,Configure secret-conf.properties properly by referring to http://docs.wso2.org/display/Carbon402/WSO2+Carbon+Secure+Vault
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.security.vault.MediationSecurityAdminService.handleException(MediationSecurityAdminService.java:83)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.security.vault.MediationSecurityAdminService.doEncrypt(MediationSecurityAdminService.java:54)
```

****"

Thanks in Advance,
faisal.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 products like ESB, API Manager are built on top of the WSO2 Carbon framework. So, we can refer ESB, APIM etc. as carbon-based servers. So, please follow the configuration steps provided in the [carbon docs page on secure vault](http://docs.wso2.org/display/Carbon420/WSO2+Carbon+Secure+Vault) in the ESB. I think the guide is pretty descriptive.

Please note that the lines that begin with the symbol '#' means it's a comment. So, you should remove the '#' symbol from your /repository/conf/security/secret-conf.properties file appropriately.

Comment: its asking about class ::::::::ERROR - SecretCallbackHandlerFactory A SecretCallbackHandler cannot be found for class name : com.sample.password.callback.handler.HardCodedSecretCallbackHandler
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sample.password.callback.handler.HardCodedSecretCallbackHandler
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)

Comment: That is because you have set that class for the attribute 'keystore.identity.key.secretProvider' in the secrect-conf.properties file. You need to make a jar out of the that class, and copy it to repository/components/lib. And, then restart the server.

Comment: but i didn't write any class i wish to use default class....and error is like this   ERROR - JKSKeyStoreLoader IOError loading keyStore from ' /home/youti/Desktop/ESB/wso2/wso2esb-4.8.0/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks ' 
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Comment: You may keep the keystore.identity.key.secretProvider, keystore.identity.parameters, and keystore.trust.store.secretProvider  (The ones with two ## symbols) attributes commented out if you are using cipher-text.properties to store the encrypted passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You can use secure vault to secure pre-defined password of the configuration file that can be found in /repository/conf directory (axis2.xml, master-datasource.xml and user-mgt.xml and  so on). 1st i guess you need to identify the what the password that you want to secure. Then please configure your actual password in the cipher-text.properties file with respect to the alias. You can run the ciphertool.sh script to do other configuration in automated manner. Please refer [this](http://soasecurity.org/2012/08/12/secure-plain-text-passwords-in-wso2-carbon-configuration-files/) for more details. Please note, with default implementation, password are encrypted using the wso2carbon.jks file.